# Petalinux 2021.1 doesn't recognize the machine name for ZCU106

Tags: xilinx, petalinux

I'm trying to create and configure a Petalinux project for the ZCU106 development board. The creation of the project is successful. The general configuration also doesn't prompt any warnings. But, when I run the kernel configuration, it prompts an error stating that the machine name I've provided is invalid. The steps are as below:

1-> Creating the project

```
petalinux-create --type project --template zynqMP --name project_zcu_106
```

2-> Configuring the project with the XSA file

```
petalinux-config --get-hw-description /path/to/file.xsa
```

3-> Then I set the **DTG Settings → (template) MACHINE_NAME** and **Yocto Settings → YOCTO_MACHINE_NAME** as `zcu106-reva` and exit the configuration

4-> Lastly, I try to run the configuration for the Linux kernel and it fails.

```
petalinux-config -c kernel
```

> MACHINE=zcu106-reva is invalid. Please set a valid MACHINE in your
> local.conf, environment or other configuration file.

I was doing the same steps on **Petalinux 2018.3** and **2020.2**. There was no problem. What could be the problem this time? How should I advance?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've found the problem.

The **DTG Settings → (template) MACHINE_NAME** and **Yocto Settings → YOCTO_MACHINE_NAME** are two different things.

The **DTG Settings → (template) MACHINE_NAME** stands for the BSP files that you vary for different devices.

On the other hand, the **Yocto Settings → YOCTO_MACHINE_NAME** represents the configuration file *(.conf)* that the Yocto will use to configure the system. Here is an explanation that describes it from the Yocto Project's mailing list:

> The MACHINE is simply a pointer to a machine-specific configuration
> file. So if you set your MACHINE=foo, then somewhere in your bblayer
> path(s) you need to make sure that a conf/machine/foo.conf is
> available. Then it will use that.

So, I only changed it to `zynqmp-generic` and it works :)